# How to use the as.POSIXlt() and solve the error of character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Tags: r, date, type-conversion, character, finance

I was working on an assignment,

```
library(tidyverse)
library(quantmod)
library(lubridate)

macro <- c("GDPC1", "CPIAUCSL","DTB3", "DGS10", "DAAA", "DBAA", "UNRATE", "INDPRO", "DCOILWTICO")

rm(macro_factors)
for (i in 1:length(macro)){
  getSymbols(macro[i], src = "FRED")
  data <- as.data.frame(get(macro[i]))
  data$date <- as.POSIXlt.character(rownames(data))
  rownames(data) <- NULL
  colnames(data)[1] <- "macro_value"
  
  data$quarter <- as.yearqtr(data$date)
  data$macro_ticker <- rep(macro[i], dim(data)[1])
  
  data <- data%>%
    mutate(date = ymd(date))%>%
    group_by(quarter)%>%
    top_n(1,date) %>%
    filter(date >= "1980-01-01", date <= "2019-12-31") %>%
    
    if(i == 1){macro_factors <- data} else {macro_factors <- rbind(macro_factors, data)}
}
```

but this came out

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(rownames(data)) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I try follow the online tutorial of using as.POSIXct() by convert the data from charater to numeric first, but it did not work for my case, and I check the class of the data and the data shown like "year-month-day", and is in the class of character, supposedly the function as.POSIXlt() will work right?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

- POSIXlt class should not be used in data frames.  Also do not use POSIXct for dates since you can get into needless time zone problems.
- to convert an xts object, such as the object produced by `getSymbols`  , to a data frame use `fortify.zoo`
- depending on what you want to do you might not need to convert from xts to a data frame in the first place.  Suggest reading about xts and zoo in the documentation of those packages.

This gives a list of data frames L and then a long data frame DF containing them all.

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))    
library(quantmod)  # also brings in xts and zoo

macro <- c("GDPC1", "CPIAUCSL")

getData <- function(symb) symb %>%
    getSymbols(src = "FRED", auto.assign = FALSE) %>%
    aggregate(as.yearqtr, tail, 1) %>%
    window(start = "1980q1", end = "2019q4") %>%
    fortify.zoo

L <- Map(getData, macro)
DF <- bind_rows(L, .id = "id")
```